# can I copy a 1d array into a 2d structure without using a loop in c?

Tags: c, arrays

If I have a big 1d array declared like this

```
1darray = malloc(N*sizeof(double))
```

and I have another structure declared like this

```
for j:A

  2dstructure[j] = malloc(C[j]*sizeof(double*))     

  for i:B

    2dstructure[j][i] = malloc(D*sizeof(double))

  end
end
```

And the size of A*B = N, that means sizeof(1darray) == sizeof(2dstructure)

Is there a way I can copy what I have in 1d array to the 2d structure without using a loop?

Comment: Try memcpy(1darray, 2darray, sizeof(1darray[0]), lengthOf1DArray)?

Comment: hmmm but wouldn't the memory not being contiguous as the below comment mentions be a problem?

Comment: then i suppose there's no way around without a loop.

Comment: A pointer to pointer is not a 2D array. C has natively 2D arrays that are contiguous in memory, why not use these?

Comment: @Jens because C[j] is of variable size so I need to dynamically allocate the memory

Comment: In function scope you can just to `double (*A)[n] = malloc(sizeof(double[m][n]));` and by that have a contiguous allocation where you can address elements simply through `A[i][j]`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can map your 2D indices to a linear 1D index thus:

```
int idx = j*B + i;
```

At that point, `1darray[idx]` is equivalent to `2dstructure[j][i]`.

Comment: sorry I didn't explain myself very well. What I want is to copy what I have in the 1d array into the 2d structure without using loops.

Comment: @Atirag: No, because your code above doesn't really create a 2D structure, it creates an array of pointers to arrays.  The corresponding memory will not be contiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an 1D N-element array initialised like this:

```
double *onedarray = malloc(N*sizeof(double));
```

And you want to create a 2D AxB element array, where A*B = N. You could create the data for the 2D array as a contiguous block of memory like this:

```
double *twoddata = malloc(A*B*sizeof(double));
```

And then create the structure separately, like this:

```
double **twodstructure = malloc(A*sizeof(double*));
for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
  twodstructure[i] = &twoddata[i*B];
```

Then copying from the 1D array to the 2D array, is a simple memcpy:

```
memcpy(twoddata, onedarray, N*sizeof(double));
```

And you can access your 2D array in a structured manner with code like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < B; j++)
    printf("%f\n", twodstructure[i][j]);
```

Comment: In C, don't cast the return of `malloc`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 1):

With your allocation pattern, you can't do a simple copy because of the multiple allocations in the second loop.  It depends on what you're really after.  You can arrange things so that you do just one allocation of a set of pointers — by setting up pointers into your current 1D array so that you can access it as a 2D array.  Alternatively, you can create a copy of your 1D array and then set up the pointers (2 allocations, 1 copy, 1 initialization loop).  Since the only issue is whether to copy the original allocation, the main answer will work on the original data.

You have:

```
int N, A, B;
A = ...;
B = ...;
N = A * B;

double *a_1d = malloc(N * sizeof(double));

...check and load a_1d...
```

Now you can create a 2D 'array' by:

```
double **a_2d = malloc(A * sizeof(double *));

...check that allocation succeeded...

for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
    a_2d[i] = &a_1d[i * B];
```

With this initialization done, you can now use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < A; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < B; j++)
        a_2d[i][j] = ...;
```

If you really need to duplicate the original `a_1d` array, you'd add:

```
double *a_1d_copy = malloc(N * sizeof(double));
...check that the allocation succeeded...
memmove(a_1d_copy, a_1d, N * sizeof(double));
```

and then you can reference `a_1d_copy` instead of `a_1d` in setting up `a_2d`.

Remember that when it comes time to free things, you need to release both `a_1d` and `a_2d` (and `a_2d_copy` if you're using that).